# How to access/inherit a private field property from a different ContentPage in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following ContentPage ("LoginPage") which among others prompts the user for his username and password:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WeatherApp.LoginPage"
    BackgroundImageSource="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/dc/d8/e5/dcd8e5e716b307d6ecfcbc73168fdff5--abstract-iphone-wallpaper-wallpaper-s.jpg"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">

    <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,20"
                 Spacing="20">

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Username" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Roboto" TextColor="White" FontSize="20"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Username" Placeholder="Please enter username..." FontFamily="Roboto"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Password" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Roboto" TextColor="White" FontSize="20"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Password" Placeholder="Please enter password..." IsPassword="True" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
        </StackLayout>
        
        <Button Text="Log in" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontFamily="OpenSans" TextColor="DeepSkyBlue" BackgroundColor="#bef9cf" CornerRadius="25"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WeatherApp.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            
            User user = new User();
            var username = Username.Text;
            var password = Password.Text;
            var _user = user.GetUser(username);

            if (username == _user.Username && password == _user.Password)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Log in successful", null, "OK");
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Log in failed", $"No such combination with username: {username}", "Try again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In another content page, I want to access this Entry property Username so I can use it in the "Greeting" property along with a time-based greeting (e.g. "Good evening, {username}!"). I tried the code below but again, I cannot access the properties from LoginPage:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WeatherApp.Models
{
    public class ProfilePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string greeting;
        public string Greeting
        {
            get
            {
                return greeting;
            }
            set
            {
                greeting = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Greeting));
            }
        }
    public ProfilePageViewModel()
    {

        User user = new User();
        var username = LoginPage.Username;
        var _user = user.GetUser(username);
        Greeting = TimeBasedGreeting() + ", {username}!";
    }
```

I hence need to access it, but it is a protected property.
Is there a way I can inherit the LoginPage and hence inherit its protected properties?

Comment: this is not the way to do this.  It would be a better idea to store the User object on the App class, so that you can access it from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Makes sense, I am new to Xamarin forms so still learning. But this still doesn't allow me to access the Entry field, right? I know how to access a username that is in the hardcode database, but I need the specific entry entered by the user (of course I check whether username/password combo is in the db first)

Comment: Why would you need to do that?  Once they've logged in on the Login page, their username should be stored in the user object and you don't need to know what they typed in.

Comment: @Jason Could you give me a code example please on how you would do that? Not sure if we are on the same page (but considering your experience you must be right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest thing to do is just pass the user object to the new page.  Then `ProfilePage` will have a reference to the user object and can get the username from there

```
if (username == _user.Username && password == _user.Password)
{
  await DisplayAlert("Log in successful", null, "OK");
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage(_user));
}
```

alternately, you could create a `User` property on the `App` class which will allow any page in your app to access it